# Filter distinct on both columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
+-------------------+----------------------+
| original_language | translation_language |
+-------------------+----------------------+
| en                | pl                   |
| en                | ru                   |
| pl                | en                   |
| pl                | ru                   |
| ru                | pl                   |
+-------------------+----------------------+
```

Right now there are some duplicates like **en - pl** and **pl - en** but I want to remove them.

So result should look like

```
+----+----+
| en | pl |
| en | ru |
| pl | ru |
+----+----+
```

I used group by to filter the results, but I assume I should use something else or just filter the result array on server side.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the SQL being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    least(original_language,translation_language) as Col1,
    greatest(original_language,translation_language) as Col2
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing this as:

```
select original_language, translation_language
from t
where original_language <= translation_language
union all
select original_language, translation_language
from t
where original_language > translation_language and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.original_language = t.translation_language and
                        t2.translation_language = t.original_language 
                 );
```

With an index on `t(original_language, translation_language)`, then this is essentially two scans on the table, along with index lookups (which are cheap).  Under most circumstances, that should be faster than a `select distinct`.

In addition, all language pairs in the result set were also in the original data.

Comment: Shouldn't the second query in the union use `>` (or the first if you prefer) ?